# Django adds an extra "/" in the url?

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/1//
Using the URLconf defined in products.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='home']
contact/
admin/
products/ [name='product-list']
products/
products/ <int:id>/ [name='product-detail']
products/ <int:id>/delete/ [name='product-delete']
products/
about/
The current path, products/1//, didn’t match any of these
```

Why does it require an extra slash after the id? The more I deal with it, the more slashes it wants. I have urls.py like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    product_detail_view,
    product_create_view,
    render_initial_data,
    dynamic_lookup_view,
    product_delete_view,
    product_list_view)

app_name = 'product'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', product_list_view, name='product-list'),
    path('', product_create_view),
    path('<int:id>/', dynamic_lookup_view, name='product-detail'),
    path('<int:id>/delete/', product_delete_view, name='product-delete'),
    path('', product_detail_view),
]
```

Also another urls.py with something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('product.urls')),
    path('about/', about_view),
]
```

Here's the function:

```
def dynamic_lookup_view(request, id):
    #obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    #obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    try:
        obj = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    context = {
        'object': obj
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_detail.html", context)
```

So it raises the exception because it was looking for the additional "/", but where did it come from?

product_list.html has this:

```
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <p>{{ instance.id }} - <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}/">{{ instance.title }}</a></p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/1//`? Could you verify if you really accessed `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/1/`? Or maybe just `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/1`?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano When I access it vie the list I get the error. product_list looks like this:  `{% for instance in object_list %}
    <p>{{ instance.id }} - <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}/">{{ instance.title }}</a></p>

{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the extra slash was coming from how you are displaying the link in your template

```
<a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}/">{{ instance.title }}</a>
```

You might want to try remove the extra slash

```
<a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}">{{ instance.title }}</a>
```

In reference, this is how it's done in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)

```
<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.name }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add APPEND_SLASH = TRUE/FALSE in your settings.py as per your requirement.
When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns provided by you in your urls.py it appends a slash and makes another request to same URL with appended slash.